# How to use LIKE in MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-like

I have a code it's working with MysQl but does not work in MySQLi:

```
function CheckBlocked($table, $thisip, $service) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE code = '$service' AND b_contents LIKE '%.$thisip.%'";
    $query=mysqli_query($dbconnect,$sql);
    $num=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($num > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to used in MySQLi ?

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: `'%.$thisip.%'"` Get rid of the dots, you're interpolating, not concatenating.

Comment: i try but dose not work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this code :

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE code = '$service' AND b_contents LIKE '%".$thisip."%' ";
```

Comment: While you are not wrong, you are mixing concatenating and interpolating strings. Best to follow Jon's comment for the correct answer

Comment: i need help pls,